# GORM is not saving my hasMany entity

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So I am asking a lot about GORM lately because it's the first time I am using it, and each time I have some issues with relations between objects and saving them.
So this is one class:

```
class TesterUser {

@Id
private String id

private String userId

static belongsTo = Dashboard

static constraints = {
    userId nullable: true
}

static mapping = {
    id column: 'id', generator: 'assigned'
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}   
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

And this is the other class:

class TestingClass {

```
@Id
private String id

private Date created
private Date modified

private String title

private ClassName className

static hasMany = [testUsers : TesterUser, sheets : Sheet]
static belongsTo = ClassName

static constraints = {
    modified nullable: true
    title nullable: true
    className nullable: true
}

static mapping = {
    sheets column:'testingClassId',joinTable: false
    testUsers column:'testingClassId',joinTable: false
    id column: 'id', generator: 'assigned'
    title column: "title", length: 90000
}

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}
public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
public Date getModified() {
    return modified;
}
public void setModified(Date modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public DavUser getClassName() {
    return className;
}
public void setClassName(ClassName className) {
    this.className = className;
}   
public Date getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

I already saved the objects in the DB, but now I want to set the relations between them and when I call and save them it's not working:

```
TesterUser testU = TesterUser.findById(uId)
TestingClass testC = TestingClass.findById(cId)
if(testU != null && testC != null){
amountOfRelations++
testC.addToDashboardUsers(testU)
if(!dtestC.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)){
amountOfUnsaved++
}
else{
amountOfsaved++
}
```

For some reason, I get no error. Not only that, I can see the queries are going to my db, but nothing happens. There is no update and no error.
I have no idea why it's not working.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to flush the previous DB and restart your application again..

Comment: Where is `TestingClass.dashboardUsers`? You have two *many* associations in `TestingClass`: `testUsers` and `sheets`. So maybe you need to be running `testC.addToTestUsers(testU)`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was not able to save my entities.
My 'solution' was to save the entity in the first place using `addTo` method.
I still don't know why it didn't work or what I needed to do in order to make my entity to be saved, but still I got a workaround.

Comment: I have same problem. Any idea so far?